# Setting a custom font to an XML file obtained from a remote server

Tags: android, textview, xml-parsing, saxparser, custom-font

I am parsing an XML file obtained from this [link](http://192.168.1.31:81/Udayavani/android/weather/weather.php?city=bangalore) where in, some of the tag values have a custom fonts which are to be stored in TextViews. I have tried setting the custom Typeface to these TextViews by using,

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kan);
kannada= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/brhknd.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(kannada);
```

But I am unable to set the required typefaces.Where am I going wrong.Anybody please guide me on this.

Comment: are unable to set the custom font or failed in retrieving values?

Comment: I am getting the values but not in the required typeface.Its displaying in the form few boxes.